# How to cancel jQuery effect by clicking anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
  $(".label").removeClass("active");
});

$(".input-combo").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();

  var $this = $(this),
      label = $this.find(".label");

  $(".label").removeClass("active");
  label.addClass("active");
});
```

And apart from the `$(document)` click part it works ok, but with the document part the first `click` event cancels out the `$(".input-combo")` click event. How could I prevent this?

Comment: In your document click handler, check what the _target_ of the click event was first.

Answer (score 1):

Following Code should work:

```
$(document:not(.input-combo)).click(function(e){
  $(".label").removeClass("active");
});

$(".input-combo").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
      label = $this.find(".label");

  $(".label").removeClass("active");
  label.addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .not() selector in which you will exclude all the functions you don't want to remove.